# After setting __import__ to None why I can still import?

Tags: python

If I do this:

```
__import__ = None
```

Then import a module:

```
import random
```

I still can. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't call the reference in your module.  It uses the one in builtins.  Try:

```py
import builtins
builtins.__import__ = None
import random
```

And you'll see it fail with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Is there a way to recover from this state?

Comment: AFAIK, you can only recover if you saved a reference to the value before changing it.  You'd save it (`saved_import = builtins.__import__`), clobber it (`builtins.__import__ = None`), and then restore it later (`builtins.__import__ = saved_import`).